# Is css property "top" a string or number in javascript?

Tags: css, string, numbers, properties

say I write the following javascript code:

```
var top = document.getElementById("SOMEDIVID").style.top;
```

Would the variable "top" end up storing the top value as a string or as a number? I want it to be a number.

Answer (score 2):

It is a complex value - a number followed by a unit.

If a unit is missing, it is assumed to be pixels (px).

So, all of these are valid:

```
80px
80
50%
17em
```

Answer (score 2):

use [parseInt()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) then

```
var top = parseInt(document.getElementById("SOMEDIVID").style.top);
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be a string. You can split off the integer with regular expression then a recast.

```
parseInt(top.match(/^\d+/)[0]); // integer only
```

Answer (score 1):

This will tell you if it's a string or a number:

```
var type = typeof( top );
```

If it's a string, this will give you a number

```
var number = parseInt( top );
```